# Android - Access ListView items when Activity is loaded

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listview` populated with `relativelayouts` which have controls themselves. The problem is that I can't access these items before the activity UI is fully loaded (I get a `null pointer exception`. There's no `OnActivityLoaded()` method and here is what I tried to do:

1. Trying to access from `OnStart()` and `OnResume()`;
2. I have a Custom `Adapter` but some of the functions I need to use
   are in the main activity, so it's a no-go;
3. Using a `Handler.postDelayed` to access the elements after a given amount of
   time. This works on high-end devices but on low-end ones the delay
   time is not enough for loading (Even if I set it as high as 1000
   ms) so I still get the `null pointer exception`.

So I need a better and proper way to access those widgets **from the main activity**.

Any thoughts? Is there a way to know when  the UI is fully displayed?

**Edit:** here's my code that I need to access after the activity is loaded.

```
                    // These 4 widgets are ones from the relativelayout which is an item in the listview
                    homeSemester = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.home_profile_semester);
                    homeSpecialty = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.home_profile_specialty);
                    homefbPP = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.home_profile_fbPP);
                    homefbName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_profile_fbName);

                    // On click listeners
                    homeSemester.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    // These functions need to be in the main activity (have access to widgets, savedInstance bundles and shared preferences
                            // Configure specialty
                            configSpecialty();
                            // Load Schedule
                            loadSchedule();
                            // Refresh contact list
                            loadContacts();
                            configurePush();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Please select your Semester!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e("Initialization", "No semester selected! This should not happen!");
                        }
                    });

                    homeSpecialty.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                            // Load schedule
                            loadSchedule();
                            // Refresh contact list
                            loadContacts();
                            // Save Data
                            saveData();
                            configurePush();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            Log.e("Initialization", "No specialty selected! This should not happen!");
                        }
                    });

                    // All of these depend on homesemester and homespecialty
                    // Read data
                    readSemester();         
                    readSpecialty();

                    // Show all button
                    contactAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v) { 
                            if(contactAll.isChecked())
                                loadAll();
                            else
                                loadContacts();
                        }
                    });

                    if(contactAll.isChecked())
                        loadAll();
                    else
                        loadContacts();

                    loadSchedule();

                    if (sharedPref.getInt("LoggedIn", 0) == 0)
                    {    
                        // Actions taken on buttons click
                        fbLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            public void onClick(View v) { 
                                if (fbLogin.getText().toString().equals("Log in with Facebook"))
                                {
                                    // Welcome Message
                                    ab.setSubtitle("Logging in...");

                                    // Login to Facebook
                                    NetAvailable = isNetworkAvailable();
                                    if (NetAvailable)
                                    {
                                        logIn(); 
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ab.setSubtitle("No Internet Connection!");
                                    }

                                    editor.putInt("LoggedIn", 1);
                                    editor.commit();
                                } 
                                else
                                {
                                    // Log Out
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builderfb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Launch.this);
                                    builderfb.setTitle("Log Out")
                                    .setMessage("Are you sure do you want to Log Out?\n\nNote: Logging out from Facebook will close the application. Next time you start ULFG2 App2Date, you will be prompted to Log in manually.")
                                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                                               
                                            editor.putInt("LoggedIn", 0);
                                            editor.commit();
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    AlertDialog welcomeMsg = builderfb.create();
                                    welcomeMsg.show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fbLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            public void onClick(View v) { 
                                // Log Out only is needed
                                AlertDialog.Builder builderfb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Launch.this);
                                builderfb.setTitle("Log Out")
                                .setMessage("Are you sure do you want to Log Out?\n\nNote: Logging out from Facebook will close the application. Next time you start ULFG2 App2Date, you will be prompted to Log in manually.")
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                                               
                                        editor.putInt("LoggedIn", 0);
                                        editor.commit();
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                                AlertDialog welcomeMsg = builderfb.create();
                                welcomeMsg.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    homefbName.setText(sharedPref.getString("student_name", "Student"));
                    homefbPP.setProfileId(sharedPref.getString("student_id", ""));
                }
```

In the `onCreate()`:

```
            ab = getSupportActionBar();
            ab.setTitle("App2Date");
            abDL = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
            abLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<View>();
            navDrawerItems.add(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_profile, null));
            adapter = new NDListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
            abLV.setAdapter(adapter);
            abLV.setDivider(null);
            abLV.setDividerHeight(0);
            // setting the nav drawer list adapter
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

            abDT = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, abDL,
                    R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer,
                    R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close) 
            {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_close);
                }
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_open);
                }
            };

            abDL.setDrawerListener(abDT);
            abDT.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

And I'm getting the `null pointer exception` in the `onCreate()` if I call the first lines of code (Under Edit:)

Comment: Post your code as well.

Comment: You'd have to show the code you have tried for the listview and the adapter and the stack trace where you get the null pointer exception.

Comment: where is setContentView?

Comment: At the very first beginning of `onCreate()`!
`@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);
....}`